# jquery adding elements using loop before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add 8 checkboxes, numbered from 11 to 18, using jquery.

My javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 for (i = 11; i < 19; i++) {
   $("#container").append("<div class=\"round-button\"><div class=\"round-button-circle\"><label><input type=\"checkbox\" value=" + i + "><span>" + i + "</span></label></div></div>");
}
});
</script>
```

The html is simply

```
<div id="#container"></div>
```

Update: The fiddle is working, but not working in html. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select2-bootstrap.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        for (i = 11; i < 19; i++) {
            $("#container").append("<div class=\"round-button\"><div class=\"round-button-circle\"><label><input type=\"checkbox\" value=" + i + "><span>" + i + "</span></label></div></div>");
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The css is in styles.css

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/of5bj24m/) should be ok except the `#` in the html for ID

Comment: **[`See works fine here`](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/s8vhacg5/2/)**. Remove `#` from `container` in `html`

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't save the change in jsfiddle lol, so it's showing the old text. Anyway the problem is solved, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove # from id of div, Just give id to div like

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtju592w/

Comment: Damn, such silly mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the question, can you please help?

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Comment: why have you not added jquery file??

Comment: I get this error : testJS.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: yes because you have not added jquery file:  please add <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> this file in the beginning of page

Comment: Thanks, yeah it works now